# Extract values from multiple elements and format them on the clipboard to paste into spreadsheet - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clipboard, getelementbyid

I have a form with 21 elements of types 'input', 'select' and 'textArea', and I have an array of 21 element id's that correspond to these elements.

I'm trying to extract the 21 values of these elements and concatenate them into one long string, with a tab inserted between each value. The intention is to put this string on the clipboard and manually paste it into a row on a spreadsheet.

In the (non working) code below, at the line 'nextValue = ...' , the console says that nextElement is null, indicating that an element with that id doesn't exist.  But it does exist.  Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks.

```
//this function is called by the onclick event of a button.
function clipToExcel() {
     let element_Ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5', 'id6', 'id7', 'id8',  
                        'id9', 'id10',  'id11', 'id12', 'id13',  'id14', 'id15', 
                        'id16', 'id17', 'id18', 'id19', 'id20', 'id21'];

     let nextElement, nextValue, valueString = "";
     for (let i = 0;  i < element_Ids.length;  i++) {   
       nextElement = document.getElementById(element_Ids[i]);   
       nextValue = nextElement.value;
// console.log(nextValue);              
       valueString += nextValue + "\t";
     }
     navigator.clipboard.writeText(valueString);

     alert('Data is now on the Clipboard in a format that can be Pasted into Excel');
}
```

Comment: Thank-you, zer00ne, that does indeed return my concatenation of values, but it also returns so much more that I don't want because there are other elements on the form.

I'd like to keep using the array of element ids as the source for the loop because it lets me easily change the order that the values are returned, which determines which column of the spreadsheet the value is headed for.  As it is, they'll be returned in the order they appear in the code, but I can reorder the ids in the array so the returned values stay in sync with the static headings at the top of the sheet.

Comment: @zer00ne -- Thanks for the update, but I'm having problems in trying to run the code.  Console complains about the leading "." in ".as-console-row-code" and in ".as-console-row::after". Calls it an "unexpected token".  Also, console says that "allFieldsNamedA" is not iterable.

Comment: @zer00ne  (cont'd) I wasn't very clear about my code requirements because I thought the answer would just be a modification of the code I presented, but there are other considerations.  The form contains more elements than shown in the array of id's, but only the elements whose id's are in the array should be considered, and all others ignored.  After the code runs, the clipboard should contain the values for only these elements, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You have everything in a `<form>` then it's easier than you think. Details are commented in example below. For more info on the form interface read on [.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) property.

```js
// Reference the form
const form = document.forms[0];
// Reference all fields of form
const io = form.elements;
// this is just to generate inputs for demo
for (let i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
  io[i].value = i;
}

/* 
Gather all form controls into a
HTMLCollection then convert it into an array
*/
const allFieldsNamedA = io.A;

// Iterate with .map()
const str = [...allFieldsNamedA].map(inp => inp.value + '\t');

// Then .join() the array into one string
console.log(str.join(''));
```

```css
.as-console-row::after {
  width: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
  <input name='A'>
</form>
```